# Crank-Nicolson Method for growing partciles

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am simulating the development of the composition of spherical particles with time.
Currently I am using the Crank-Nicolson method for radial diffusion and it works just fine.

Problem is, that those particles grow or shrink over time (~1/r). My question is now, how to include that into the CN-scheme in the best possible way.

I only see three possiblilities:

1. Take the new concentration profile with the new radius and the new outer radius concentration (this one is known), interpolate new values for the lateral resolution, and feed it back for the next iteration.
   The interpolation has to be done, since for the growth increment dx, I do not know that concentrazion at r+-dx, and the interpolation also asures a  uniform distribution auf my radial increments. Disadvatage, the radial increments change in size, so I have to setup the CN-matrix again, for each timestep, This takes time, als well as the interpolation. Not sure if I want that, when time is crucial, but its accurate...
2. Do not consider the growth increment dx (sum it up over time), untill its larger than the radial increments. Then just add the new column and line the the CN-matrix, with the new outer radius and the new concentration. Advantage, radial increments remain constant. Therefore the matrix has not to be recalculated, just add a new line. Disadvantage, its not accurate since I disrecard the correct radius at the outer boundary, but just adding lines to the matrix should be faster then recalculating the matrix, even when the matrix growth over time
3. Non-uniform radial distribution. Should be most accurate. But the theoretically infinitisimal small size auf the growth increment dx ( which will then also be my lateral increment) will lead to incredible small time increments, according to von neumann, which will take a long time.

So maybe I did oversee something and there is a better approach for this problem, but do you have any recommendation for something like this?

Comment: Please choose the right tags for your question. von Neumann algebras have nothing to do with your problem.